# Deep set python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am having a saved list of Python dict keys:

`['level_one', 'level_two', 'test']`

These are the keys of a dictionary:

```
mydict = {
    'level_one' : {
        'level_two' : {
            'test' : "Hello World"
        }
    }
}
```

Normally I could set the `test` key like this:

`mydict['level_one']['level_two']['test'] = "Hello StackOverflow"`

Unfortunately, the list/dict are generated on the fly, and I don't know how deep it can go. Is there a possibility to update the dict key by the list of keys without using braces?

I only was able to reflect this functionality for getting the string:

```
def deepGet(sourceDict, *keys):
    return reduce(lambda d, k: d.get(k) if d else None, keys, sourceDict)

> deepGet(mydict, *['level_one', 'level_two', 'test'])
>> Hello World
```

**Not a duplicate. This is regarding setting, not getting of nested dictionary.**

Comment: `pop()` the last item of the list, use your `deepGet` on it and set the popped off key on the resulting `dict`.

Comment: @KlausD. Sounds like an idea! I will give it a try :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We need a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) that will keep making new instances of itself all the way down.

```
import collections

recursive_dict = lambda: collections.defaultdict(recursive_dict)

mydict = recursive_dict()
```

At this point, you can simplify your `deepGet` to just use [`operator.getitem`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.getitem) instead of the lambda you have now.  `operator.getitem` is "shorthand" for `lambda a, b: a[b]`.

As for setting a key, you can just write a loop:

```
keys = ['level_one', 'level_two', 'test']
d = mydict
for key in keys[:-1]:
    d = d[key]
d[keys[-1]] = 'Hello World'
```

If dictionaries are missing, the defaultdict will silently create them, no need to check for them first.

Converting this to a `reduce()` call is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 8):

There is now a way to deep set values dynamically, without changing the container type to a defaultdict or some other dynamically creating type: [glom.assign()](https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#glom.assign).

A usage example with your case:

```py
import glom

target = {}
path = 'level_one.level_two.test'

glom.assign(target, path, 'hello world', missing=dict)
# {'level_one': {'level_two': {'test': 'hello world'}}}
```

Notice we passed the `missing=dict`, telling glom to create missing keys with the built-in dict constructor. You'll also need to `pip install glom`, but it's pure-Python and compatible with Python 2, 3, and PyPy.

There's a lot more you can do with [glom](https://github.com/mahmoud/glom/), especially around deep getting and setting. I should know, since (full disclosure) I created it. That means if you find a gap, you should [let me know](https://github.com/mahmoud/glom/issues)!